# pg_fetch_assoc returning 1 after values

Tags: postgresql, web

I am beginner in PHP, i am working with session and pg functions. So i want to return user's first name and last name from database(basically user's details) and display it to different page using session. and it is returning using pg_fetch_assoc() but the problem is like it is showing 1 after every value like (firstname 1), (lastname 1). How can i fix it. is there any other way to return values from database and display it and also use these values as conditions.

Thanks

Below is my code:

```
$login = trim($_POST['login']);
    $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);


    $result = pg_execute($conn, "login_query", array($login, hash(HASH_ALGO, $pass)));

    $records = pg_num_rows($result);


    if($records == 1){
         $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);

        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $row['last_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_access'] = $row['last_access'];
        $_SESSION['user_type'] = $row['user_type'];
        //$_SESSION['details'] = $row; 
        pg_execute($conn, "update_query", array($login));


    /*  $_SESSION['output'] = $output();*/

        $_SESSION['output'] = "Welcome back " . pg_fetch_result($result,0,"first_name") . pg_fetch_result($result,0,"last_name").'</br>';
        $_SESSION['output'] .= "Our records show that your </br>" . "email address is " . pg_fetch_result($result,0,"email_address") . "</br>";
        $_SESSION['output'] .= "and you last accessed our system: " . pg_fetch_result($result,0,"last_access") . "</br>"; 


        header('location: ./user-dashboard.php');

    }
```

[image]

here is `var_dump($row);` value:

```
array(9) { ["user_id"]=> string(20) "jdoe " ["password"]=> string(32) "179ad45c6ce2cb97cf1029e212046e81" ["user_type"]=> string(2) "c " ["email_address"]=> string(256) "jdoe@gmail.com " ["first_name"]=> string(128) "John " ["last_name"]=> string(128) "Doe " ["birth_date"]=> string(10) "1998-02-05" ["enrol_date"]=> string(10) "2017-01-01" ["last_access"]=> string(10) "2017-10-18" }
```

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFjah.png)

Comment: whats inside `login_query`?..

Comment: $stmt1 = pg_prepare($conn, "login_query",  "SELECT first_name, last_name, email_address, last_access FROM users WHERE user_id = $1 AND password = $2");

Comment: if you add `var_dump( $row);` after defining it - you see "good" values?..

Comment: it's still same after using `var_dump( $row);`. I don't know what's happening. what is 1 here, the number of rows or boolean value. @VaoTsun

Comment: `var_dump( $row);` shows the value of variable - please update question with result

Comment: so the values have extra space at the end, but no trailing 1. so the problem is not `pg_fetch_assoc` - please find part of code that displays the page on screenshot - bug is there

Comment: I was too looking on spaces but in database there is no spaces.

Comment: But see the value of last_access, there is no space in it but it is also showing 1 after date

Comment: spase and 1 are not related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<h1 class="floating-box" ><?php echo print_r($_SESSION['first_name'],True); ?></h1>
        <h1 class="floating-box" ><?php echo print_r($_SESSION['last_name']); ?></h1>
        <h1 class="floating-box" ><?php echo print_r($_SESSION['last_access']); ?></h1>`

Sorry, i forgot to add true in print_r() function. Thanks for your help. @Vao Tsun

Answer (score 0):

`pg_fetch_assoc` returns values OK. you can see it in result of `var_dump($row);` - see the `["last_name"]=> string(128) "Doe "` - it has extra space - yes, but not *1*. So another bit of code adds *1* after `$row["last_name"]` value.

Comment: but why it is adding 1 after the date. there is no space in date. `["last_access"]=> string(10) "2017-10-18"`

Comment: space is UNRELATED to *1*. Also  `pg_fetch_assoc` is unrelated to *1* - please ask a different question posting the code that populates data to the page to debug the source of that *1*